# How to update the profile readme automatically

Tags: git, github, yaml, profile, readme

I have a repository located at the following URL: https://github.com/MateiMartin/MateiMartin/tree/main.

Within this repository, there is a README file that I wish to update automatically every 30 minutes, utilizing a specific .yaml file.
Unfortunately, I am encountering difficulties in achieving this task.

I have attempted to utilize git commands within the run section, but I consistently encounter errors. Could someone provide assistance in resolving this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include more details, such as **which**
 errors you encounter and which specific code you tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Try the following

You can create a GitHub Actions workflow with a schedule trigger. Here's an example of how you can set it up:

1. In your repository, create or edit the README file that you want to update automatically.
2. Create a .github/workflows/update-readme.yml file in the repository. This file will contain the workflow configuration.
3. Open the update-readme.yml file and add the following content:

```
name: Update README every 30 minutes

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/30 * * * *"

jobs:
  update-readme:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Update README
        run: |
          # Add your script or commands here to automatically generate the README content
          echo "This README was updated at $(date)" > README.md

      - name: Commit and push changes
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git add README.md
          git commit -m "Update README" || echo "No changes to commit"
          git push
```

4. Customize the run section under "Update README" with your own script or commands that generate or modify the content of the README file.
5. Commit and push the update-readme.yml file to your repository.

Once the workflow is set up, it will run automatically every 30 minutes based on the specified cron schedule.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: I tried something like that and it always gives errors

Comment: You can see my workflow [here](https://github.com/montasim/montasim/actions/runs/5491928320/workflow) to have an idea